# Parsing JSON with Codable, swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

I am using Swift 4 and Codables to parse JSON.

Following is my JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "email": "testuser14324@testuser.com",
        "cityUserId": 38,        
        "CityUser": {
            "isEmailVerified": false,
            "UserId": 711
        },
        "tokenInfo": {
            "accessToken": "eyJsds"
        }
    },
    "error": false
}
```

Following is the Model I am using

```
struct RootClass : Codable {
    let data : Data?
    let error : Bool?
}
```

For Data:

```
struct Data : Codable {

    let cityUser : CityUser?
    let cityUserId : Int?
    let email : String?
    let tokenInfo : TokenInfo?
}
```

For CityUser :

```
struct CityUser : Codable {

    let userId : Int?
    let isEmailVerified : Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userId = "UserId"
        case isEmailVerified = "isEmailVerified"
    }
}
```

For Token :

```
struct TokenInfo : Codable {

    let accessToken : String?
}
```

Decoding it as :

```
 let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootClass.self, from: resJson as! Data)
```

Problem :

```
response.data?.email = testuser14324@testuser.com
response.data?.tokenInfo?.accessToken = eyJsds
response.data?.cityUser = nil
```

It is returning correct email, cityUserId, tokenInfo.accessToken but it is returning "nil" for "CityUser". What shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

That's the big disadvantage of declaring everything as optional. You get `nil` but you have no idea, why .

It's just a typo: The property must match the spelling of the key (starting with capital letter in this case)

```
let CityUser : CityUser?
```

However to conform to the Swift naming convention it's recommended to use `CodingKeys` to transform uppercase to lowercase and if necessary *snake_case* to *camelCase*. By the way, `Data` is a struct in the Foundation framework in Swift 3+, use another name for example

```
struct ProfileData : Codable {

    let cityUser : CityUser
    let cityUserId : Int
    let email : String
    let tokenInfo : TokenInfo

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cityUser = "CityUser"
        case cityUserId, email, tokenInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: The recommended solution is the latter: change the `CodingKey`s value to match the property, not the other way around. (Keeping in mind that you have to supply the other coding keys to match the rest of the properties as well.)

Comment: @ItaiFerber I know, I just wanted to point to the uppercase / lowercase mismatch. I updated the answer.

Comment: @vadian what is need to take `CityUser` in `CodingKey `..may you please tell me? or in which scenario we have to take entity in `CodingKey`

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @vadian i mean why you put `case cityUserId, email, tokenInfo` in `private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey  { }` i am not able to understand it.can't we declare `cityUserId,email ` in `struct ProfileData : Codable { }` rather than `private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey  { }` block

Comment: If you specify `CodingKeys` for example to map one key to a different named property you have to add all other keys you want to be en-/decoded.

Comment: Thank you @vadian sir, now i understand if i want to change one key in `CodingKeys ` then i have to add all other key in `CodingKeys ` is it right ?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for, [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) what I use for parsing if I want to parse through codables. Ofcourse you can write and edit model provided from above tool  by yourself too  .